# Regex: Get matches before a single character on each line

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to do some regex matching using JavaScript on the following text:

> Text: blah
>
> Some Text: blah
>
> Some more text: blah blah
>
> Other Text: blah blah

I want to match all the words before each colon: `Text`, `Some Text`, `Some more text`, `Other Text`. So far I've only been able to match the first occurrence only, with this expression: `/^(.*?):/g` (Group 1).

How do I match all occurrences? (There is exactly one colon on each line).

From what I have read I think I need to use `[\s\S]`, but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look for characters up to the first `:` but make the match operate on a "multi-line" basis using the `m` flag:

```
/^([\w ]+?):/gm
```

Check out the visual example at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/c8QPZc/3).

And check out the example of getting all the matches from the entire block of text into an array:

```js
let text = `
Text: blah
Some Text: blah
Some more text: blah blah
Other Text: blah blah
`;

let captures = [];
text.replace(/^([\w ]+?):/gm, (match, capture) => {
  captures.push(capture);
});

console.log(captures);
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm using this in conjunction with the String.replace() method. How would I reference the first group (text before the colon) for each of the four matches? I tried doing: `text.replace(/([\w ]+?):/gm, "...$&...");`, but it includes the commas. How would I exclude the commas?

Comment: Sorry, just saw your code snippet, instead of using the `capture` field is there another way using `$`?

Comment: @Jake Are you referring using the capture without the colon? If so, you'll want to use the `$1` operator to grab the captures: `text.replace(/([\w ]+?):/gm, "...$1...");`

Comment: Your code works without the `m` flag, because the `m` flag does not do what you apparently think it does. It merely controls the meaning of `^` and `$`.

Comment: @torazaburo, oops, I understand what it does, and was using `^` while writing up my initial answer, but then noticed the portion of the answer that said there was only ever 1 colon per line so I removed ^ and forgot to remove the `m` flag. Thanks for catching it. I went ahead and put the ^ back in because who knows, there may be places where a colon finds its way further into the string.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [*lookahead assertion*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-non-capturing-parentheses) (`(?=`) to match the colon, together with the [`m` flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Advanced_searching_with_flags) which lets you use `^` to match the beginning of the line:

```js
let text = `Text: blah
Some Text: blah
Some more text: blah blah
Other Text: blah blah`;
    
console.log(text.match(/^.*(?=:)/gm));
```

This has the advantage that you can painlessly replace just the matched portions:

```js
let text = `Text: blah
Some Text: blah
Some more text: blah blah
Other Text: blah blah`;
        
console.log(text.replace(/^.*(?=:)/gm, m => `...${m}...`));
```